# C#: Получение коллекции данных с помощью регулярного выражения в многострочном режиме

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

### Задача

В C#-программе получить из текстового файла телефонные коды городов и их названия с помощью регулярного выражения.

- Для простоты в данной задаче будем брать только названия городов, состоящие из одного слова без дефиса.
- Логично будет, если в файле данных сначала шло бы название города, а потом код, но я по определённым причинам сделал наоборот.
- В идеале, если в файле данных строка будет начинаться с кода города, а потом через один пробел будет идти его название, но идеология юзабилити требует адаптации к криворуким пользователям, потому регулярное выражение должно допускать пробелы до кода, лишние пробелы после него, а также лишние пробелы после названия города. Недопустимо лишь отсутствие пробела между кодом и городом.

### Файл данных

```
39032 Абакан
  39042  Саяногорск
39031 Черногорск       

     39036Копьево   
42722 Анадыр ь
81831145 Березник
81 856   Карпогоры
```

### Составление регулярного выражения ##

На [Regex Storm .NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester) с регулярным выражением `^\s*(\d{4,5})\s+(\w)+\s*$` и опцией `Multiline` я получил 3 совпадения (первые три города), а остальные 4 паттерну не соответствуют:

- Копьево - Отсутствует пробел между кодом и именем
- Анадырь - Имеется ошибочный пробел в имени (повторюсь, что в этом вопросе мы рассматриваем только имена собственные, состоящие из одного слова).
- Березинск - Слишком много цифер в коде (несоответствие стандарту)
- Карпогоры - Пробел в номере

### Программная реализация

Как я узнал, в C# режим `Multiline` является режимом по умолчанию. С точки зрения логики, в паттерне нужно указать начало и конец строки. Тем не менее с паттерном

```
string pattern = @"^\s*(\d{4,5})\s*(\w+)\s$";
```

в программе я не получил ни одного совпадения. С паттерном `@"^\s*(\d{4,5})\s*(\w+)\s"` (без указания конца строки) я получил единственное совпадение: пустой код города и имя первого города. Наконец с паттерном `@"\s*(\d{4,5})\s*(\w+)\s"` (без указания начала и конца строки) я получил невалидные данные:

- Код первого города - пустой.
- Копьево, Анадырь - получено несмотря на невалидность
- Березинск: Получен код города `81831`; следующие три цифры зачтены как название города.

Как следует исправить код, чтобы совпадения были те же, что и на Regex Storm?

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // Указание пути к файлу данных
        String currentProjectPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDi‌​rectory, "..\\..\\")).ToString();
        String dataFolderPath = currentProjectPath + "/Data/";
        String dataFileNameWithExtension = "Data.txt";
        String fullPathToDataFile = dataFolderPath + dataFileNameWithExtension;


        // Чтение файла
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fullPathToDataFile);
        string fileContains = "";

        foreach (string line in lines) {
            fileContains = fileContains + line + "\n";
        }

        // Применение регулярного выражения
        string pattern = @"\s*(\d{4,5})\s*(\w+)\s";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(fileContains, pattern);

        foreach (Match match in matches) {
            Console.WriteLine("Код города："+ match.Groups[1].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Имя города：" + match.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Если для ответа на данный вопрос Вам нужно поэкспериментировать с кодом, то в целях экономии Вашего времени я подготовил проект для Visual Studio ([ссылка на Яндекс Диск](https://yadi.sk/d/7elk5ZL-3NYJLZ); возможно станет недоступной после получения ответа на вопрос).*

Comment: Хм, а почему вы не используете хотя бы xml? Или разделять код с наименованием запятой какой-нибудь. Ну и в конце концов вам поможет обычный string.Split

Comment: Для того, чтобы считать весь текст в одну строковую переменную, а не в массив построчно используйте File.ReadAllText

Comment: `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(...)) { var parts = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); if (parts.Length == 2) { Console.WriteLine("Код города: " + parts[0]); Console.WriteLine("Имя города: " + parts[1]); } }`

Comment: @Андрей, а вот представьте себе, некоторые заказчики требуют `.txt`, наотрез отказываясь от `.json`, `.xml` и БД. Так как предпринимательство - это решение проблем и удовлетворение потребностей заказчиков, то приходится делать как говорят.

Comment: Ок, мой вариант с string.Split попробуйте

Comment: @Андрей, результат отрицательный: код Абакана не считан, также зачён невалидный Березник (в регулярном выражении я указывал, что код города может быть от 4 до 5 символов).

Comment: С Абаканом должно сразу работать, найдите причину под отладчиком, а для Березника просто нужно добавить ещё одно условие: `parts[0].Length == 4 || ... == 5`

Comment: @Андрей, кстати, я Вас благодарю за альтернативное решение, но я хотел бы понять, что я упустил с регулярными выраженями.

Comment: Ок, с регекспами - ваша регулярка (изначальная) работает неправильно, на regexstorm внизу переключитесь на вкладку Table и посмотрите что реально возвращается.

Comment: `Как я узнал, в C# режим Multiline является режимом по умолчанию` Неправда `Все параметры регулярного выражения по умолчанию отключены.`

Comment: Зачем писать сложную регулярку? Просто удалите все пробелы

Comment: @Alex78191, для валидации данных, например код города может быть длиной не более 5 цифер. Соответственно, невалидные данные будут проигнорированы.

Comment: При удалении всех пробелов можно использовать регулярку`^(\d+)(\w+)$`, а первые 5 символов кода получить метод `Substring`.

Comment: На сайте регулярка `^(\d+)(\w+)$` [неправильно работает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iBdq.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша изначальная регулярка неверна, она возвращает код города и последовательность по одной букве:

[image: 1]

Правильная регулярка: `^\s*(\d{4,5})\s+(\w+)\s*$`:

[image: 2]

Рабочий код:

```
var lines = @"39032 Абакан
  39042  Саяногорск
39031 Черногорск       

     39036Копьево   
42722 Анадыр ь
81831145 Березник
81 856   Карпогоры";

string pattern = @"^\s*(\d{4,5})\s+(\w+)\s*$";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(lines, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Код города：" + match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Имя города：" + match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Обратите внимание, на параметр `RegexOptions.Multiline`, он:

> Изменяет ^ и $ так, чтобы они соответствовали началу/концу строки
>   текста, а не началу/концу всей строки регулярного выражения

PS: На сколько я понял [.NET Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester) как раз работает на движке регулярных выражений .NET, поэтому раз уж вы включили там галочку `Multiline`, то должны и в своем коде указать соответствующий флаг

Comment: Всё работает! Благодарю Вас за ответ!

Comment: Изначальная регулярка верна, просто доставать значения групп по индексу - ненадежный способ.

Answer (score 3):

```
var lines = @"39032 Абакан
39042  Саяногорск
39031 Черногорск       

 39036Копьево   
42722 Анадыр ь
81831145 Березник
81 856   Карпогоры";
lines = lines.Replace(" ", "");

string pattern = @"(\d{4,5})\d*(\w+)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(lines, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Код города：" + match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Имя города：" + match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

> Код города：39032
>   Имя города：Абакан
>   Код города：39042
>   Имя города：Саяногорск
>   Код города：39031
>   Имя города：Черногорск
>   Код города：39036
>   Имя города：Копьево
>   Код города：42722
>   Имя города：Анадырь
>   Код города：81831
>   Имя города：Березник
>   Код города：81856
>   Имя города：Карпогоры

Comment: Отличное решение! Прошу меня простить, галочку я поставить не могу, так как целью данного вопроса было разобраться, что я не так сделал в регулярными выражениями, но за ещё более лучше решение с благодарностью плюсую Ваш ответ.

Comment: А если длина кода будет меньше 5 символов (4 например, что допустимо по условию автора)? Substring не упадет?

Comment: @Андрей исправил

Comment: @Alex78191, не понял, как измененная регулярка повлияет на поведение Substring

Comment: @Андрей забыл удалить

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Анадырь должен попаст в результат или нет?

Comment: @PashaPash, По изначальной задаче нет, потому что данные не валидные, но предложенное решение имеет больший функционал, чем поставленная задача, а потому здесь есть исправление гипотетической ошибки ввода и зачёт исправленных данных.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu т.е. вы решили поменять условие на лету :)

Comment: @PashaPash, ну я свою ошибку понял и задачу решил в итоге, так что теперь можно поднимать планку ^ ^

Answer (score 3):

Ваша изначальная регулярка, `^\s*(\d{4,5})\s+(\w)+\s*$`, **верна**, и ничуть не хуже, чем `^\s*(\d{4,5})\s+(\w+)\s*$`. Да, из нее неудобно достать результат, но это вполне возможно кодом вида:

```
Console.WriteLine("Имя города：" + 
    String.Join("", match.Groups[2].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c=>c.Value)));
```

Дело в только в том, что доставать результат парсинга регекса, опираясь на индексы групп - не слишком надежный способ.

Надежный способ - именованные группы. Тогда все три выражения дадут вам одинаковый результат, вне зависимисти от того, как вы поставите скобки:

```
^\s*(?'code'\d{4,5})\s+(?'city'(\w)+)\s*$
^\s*(?'code'\d{4,5})\s+(?'city'\w+)\s*$
^\s*(?'code'\d{4,5})\s+(?'city'(\w+))\s*$
```

Имена групп можно обрамлять в `<>`, если одиночные кавычки режут глаз:

```
^\s*(?<code>\d{4,5})\s+(?<city>\w+)\s*$
```

Пример кода с вашей изначальной регуляркой + именами групп

```
var lines = @"39032 Абакан
39042  Саяногорск
39031 Черногорск       

 39036Копьево   
42722 Анадыр ь
81831145 Березник
81 856   Карпогоры";

string pattern = @"^\s*(?'code'\d{4,5})\s+(?'city'(\w)+)\s*$";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(lines, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Код города：" + match.Groups["code"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Имя города：" + match.Groups["city"].Value);
}
```

При этом неименованные группы можно вообще убрать из результатов, задав флаг [`RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options?view=netframework-4.7#Explicit)

Comment: Вообще-то она хуже, если доставать по индексу.

Comment: @Alex78191 да, но это вызвано тем, что доставать по индексу - плохо. А не тем, что регулярка плохая. Регулярка хорошая, валидная, совпадение находит. Способ доставания результатов - плохой :)

Comment: Я до этого момента не слышал про [именованные группы фиксации](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). Только JavaScript их не поддерживает.

Comment: Что хорошего в том, что доставать сложнее, не говорить, что это не ошибка.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну конечно, когда вы обернули и `\w` и `+` в скобки, то уже не важно как внутри это разбивается на подгруппы, а изначально у автора в группу попадает только одна буква `(\w)`, так что регулярка не верна. Просто автора ввело в заблуждение то, что на сайте выделяется цветом все совпадения, хотя если открыть вкладку `Table` видно как он на самом деле разбивает - вместо кода+слово получается набор совпадений код+однаБуква

Comment: @Alex78191 то, что JS не поддерживает группы - проблема JS. Не совсем понимаю, что значит "выгораживать". У топикастера нет ошибки, у него написано валидное выражение, просто он не знал, как из результата надежно достать значение.

Comment: @Андрей я уже выше написал, несколько раз - совершенно неважно, как там стоят скобки. Проблема не в скобках. Проблема в том, что опираться на порядок и на количество скобок в регексе - ненадежный способ. Надежный - назначить имена нужным кускам. И доставать по имени. Тогда можно хоть колонки переставлять во входных данных, хоть добавлять между колонками еще что-то - код доставания результата не поменяется.

Comment: @PashaPash, ок, уберите пару скобок которую вы добавили и поместите наименование группы в авторские скобки

Comment: @Андрей просто топикастер выбрал ненадежный способ. "переставить скобки", как вы предложили - это такое же по надежности решение, как "взять оригинальное выражене и склеить все группы после первой в одну строку, кодом!". Результат же будет валидный? Значит регулярка валидна. Но способ его получения - ужасный.

Comment: @Андрей зачем? что значит авторские скобки? автору нужно совпадение. Правильный и надежный способ его доставть - назначить этому совпадению имя и достать по имени. А то завтра между кодом и городом появится какой-нибуть почтовый индекс - и придется переписывать код доставания имени.

Comment: @Андрей т.е. ваше решение - переставить скобки. Альтенативные решения - собрать наматченное пачкой групп в строку, кодом на C#. Или назначить имя нужному куску. Мне нравится вариант "назначить имя".

Comment: @Андрей вот вам рабочий пример с авторской регуляркой и правильным результатом: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MiBKgW

Comment: @PashaPash, я имею ввиду почему вы не написали такую регулярку: `^\s*(?'code'\d{4,5})\s+(?'city'\w)+\s*$` Потому что она не сработает. Можно, конечно, собрать вручную эти буквы потом, но зачем, если `Regex` сделает это самостоятельно. Имхо, это костыли, проще сделать регулярку которая сразу даст нужный результат. А против именованных групп я против ничего не имею - они нужны и полезны.

Comment: @Андрей а почему я должен был написать такую регулярку? Я полностью согласен с утверждением, но надо написать такую регулярку, которая сразу даст нужный результат. Просто мне не нравятся "улучшения" регулярок перестановкой скобок. В этот раз оно топикастеру поможет, а в следующий - он опять будет страдать.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну суть моего ответа не только в переносе скобки, но и + некоторые уточнения нюансов реализации языка регулярок в .NET, так что я не считаю свой ответ плохим или, тем более, вредным.